# Is there any performance issue in making Array List thread using Collections. synchronized List?

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi i want to know is there any performance issue if i make `ArrayList` thread safe using `Collections.synchronizedList()` method? if there is issue, on which functionality  it  affect like addition  ,searching etc.

I am getting concurrent Modification Exception  to  get rid of it i  used Collections Synchronized  method  but later i came to know  it  has some  performance  issue? my  question  is very simple which  approach should i use without affecting  performance...

Comment: Why don't you simply use `Vector`?

Comment: Its a valid question.. Downvoters please give reasons..

Answer (score 3):

all methods of synchronized list use synchronization which will work slower than direct accesss.

java.util.Vector is an implementation of List which already has all methods synchronized

Comment: `java.util.Vector` is *almost* deprecated. Avoid using `Vector` and `Hashtable` in your code. Use other collections and use `Collections.synchronizedList()` and similar methods if and only if you *really* need synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization itself almost does not affect performance since java 1.4. However applications that are designed with a lot of synchronization blocks can run slowly because different threads are waiting each other.

There are other approaches that help us to design multi threaded applications without or with minimal synchronization.

1. use stateless architecture
2. use immutable objects
3. think about actors model

Comment: are you sure  synchronization  will not affect  performance?because my array List  is heavy . It is having more than 100 records  and  i performs  various operation on it...thanks  for  your reply @AlexR  .

Comment: @saurabh More than 100 elements in a List is ridiculously small. You can consider it to be a big list if there's 100,000 elements in it, and even then the performance issues aren't with synchronization itself.

Answer (score 0):

yeah, you incur the overhead of threads being blocked...

If you read your list more than you write to it, java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList is an option for you.  Reads will be fast with no locking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach as you are getting immutable list instance so no worry for multiple threads acccessing it.
List immutablelist = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `Collections.synchronizedList((List<T> list))` is that:   in many cases, it is not really useful.  For exmple, for iterating over all elements, 
 or when getting a value, do computations based on it, and replace it with the result, we have to use manual synchronization anyway.

Fromt the documentation of  [**`Collections.synchronizedList((List<T> list))`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29)

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned
>   list when iterating over it:
>
> ```
>   List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
>       ...
>   synchronized (list) {
>       Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
>       while (i.hasNext())
>           foo(i.next());
>   }
> ```
>
> **Failure to follow this advice may result in non-deterministic
>   behavior.**